# Tips on writing a History of Mathematics Essay

Tags: math-history

I'm a third year maths undergrad currently taking a 'History and Development of Mathematics' module.

As a maths student, you can probably guess my skills at writing an essay are a little (if not very) dusty, and wondered if anyone could give me some tips on how to structure it, and if there is anything vital I need to include?

The title is "What influence did the Pre-Christianity Babylonians and Greeks have in the development of mathematical astronomy?"

Comment: What is your outline? Any specific topics that you think might interest your audience? How much background can you assume from your readers?

Comment: "As a maths student, you can probably guess my skills at writing an essay are a little (if not very) dusty" -- maybe there is good irony and humility in this, but taken verbatim, I have to disagree strongly with the view that underlies this statement. -- Sorry, this is not directly helpful, but hey, more confidence! Who should know how to structure anything if not a mathematician?

Answer (score 1):

> *If anyone could give me some tips on how to structure it*

**Babylon**

- [Babylonian Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_mathematics)
- [Babylonian Astronomy $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_astronomy)
- [Babylonian Astronomy $2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_astronomy#Mesopotamia)
- [Babylonian Numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_numerals)

**Greece** *(and* **Egypt**, *which lies just across the Mediterranean)*

- [Greek Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_mathematics)

  - [Egyptian Geometry $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_geometry)
  - [Egyptian Geometry $2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_mathematics#Geometry)
  - [Egyptian Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_algebra)
- [Greek Mathematicians $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_ancient_Greek_mathematicians)
- [Greek Mathematicians $2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timetable_of_Greek_mathematicians)
- [Greek Astronomy $0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_astronomy#Greco-Roman_Egypt) — [Egyptian Astronomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_astronomy)
- [Greek Astronomy $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_astronomy)
- [Greek Astronomy $2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_astronomy#Greece_and_Hellenistic_world)
- [Greek Astronomers $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_astronomy#Famous_astronomers_of_antiquity)
- [Greek Astronomers $2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aAncient_Greek_astronomers)

  - [Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes)
  - [Ptolemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy) — *Post-Christian, but pagan. (Not so sure what you mean by “Pre-Christian”).*
  - [The *Almagest*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almagest)
- *Greek Astronomic Inventions*

  - [The Astrolabe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrolabe)
  - [The Antikythera Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism)

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: It should be worth noting here that citing wiki is absolutely what you don't want to do. It's good for finding preliminary information, but in terms of essays and papers, it should be a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

The "pre-christianity" part of the title is bizarre. Pretty much everything the
Babylonians did is pre-Christian. Even the Greeks did almost nothing in mathematics and astronomy after Christianity arrived on the shores of Alexandria or on the mainlands of Greece.

Other than that, there's not much you can do except reading Neugebauer (Exact Sciences in Antiquity) and [Ossendrijver](https://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~ossendrm/cuneiform.html) for the Babylonian part. As for Greek astronomy, check the web for the contributions of Eratosthenes, Aristarch and Ptolemy.